# Append element as sibling after element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How do I add a text after an HTML element using pure Javascript? There is appendChild but this adds it within the element. I would instead like to add it as a sibling after the element like this:

```
<img id="myimg" src="..." />

<script>
  var myimg = document.getElementById('myimg');
  myimg.appendAFTER('This is my caption.'); //pseudo-code and doesn't really work
</script>
```

I would like to end up with this:

```
<img id="myimg" src="..." />
This is my caption.
```

What is the Javascript equivalend of `after()` from jQuery?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Check out `Node.insertBefore()` and `Node.nextSibling` ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x9t5q/)):

```
var myimg = document.getElementById('myimg');
var text = document.createTextNode("This is my caption.");
myimg.parentNode.insertBefore(text, myimg.nextSibling)
```

or `Element.insertAdjacentHTML()` ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y7QYU/1/)):

```
var myimg = document.getElementById('myimg');
myimg.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "This is my caption.");
```

Comment: Is either of these "better practice" or more efficient? Thanks!

Comment: According to https://jsbench.me/ the first solution is almost twice as fast.

Comment: Yeah... generally, parsing HTML is going to be slow.

Answer (score 10):

Please use the following code:

```
<img id="myimg" src="..." />

<script>
  var myimg = document.getElementById('myimg');
  var txt=document.createElement("span");
  txt.innerHTML="Whatever text you want to write . . .";
  if(myimg.nextSibling){
    myimg.parentNode.insertBefore(txt,myimg.nextSibling);
  }else{
    myimg.parentNode.appendChild(txt);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You don't need to check for `.nextSibling`. `insertBefore()` will happily append the new node if the reference node is `null`.