# Is there a way to find a specific class and then add code to the layout?

Tags: php

I want to find a specific class and then insert new source code into the statement.
Is there a way?

ex. find class - point

```
<div class="wrap">
 <div class="point">content</div>
</div>
```

to do. add source code

```
<div class="wrap">
 <div class="point">content</div>
 <div class="add_source">add content</div>
</div>
```

I used a few scripts but couldn't verify them...

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Did you search for your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/21422401/6934036. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for asking a good question.

Comment: With the help of jquery/javascript you can achieve this